# Magento 2: SQL get orders with specific option id

Tags: magento2, database, orders, sql, query

I'm trying to get all orders with a specific option id to see what percentage of orders are ordered with measurement of centimeters.

Not very good with database queries and I can't seem to figure it out.

I've looked inside the `sales_order_item` table but it doesn't have an `option_id` column.

I need to find another way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Using Database :-**

**Query :-**

```
SELECT * FROM `sales_order_item` WHERE `product_options` LIKE '%2010%'
```

Replace 2010 with Your **Option Id**

---

In **sales_order_item** this table saved option id in `product_options` coumn with **`json Format`**.

You can decode this `product_options` And Apply **Filter**

> **json decode :-**

```
json_decode($product_options)
```

Comment: I need to get the amount of order items with that specific option id, is there no way of doing that through the database?

Comment: you mean filter in database ?

Comment: Yes, sorry I'm not very good with databases

Comment: ok let me check.

Comment: check updated answer

Comment: Does the 'LIKE '%2010%' filter by option id?

Comment: yes buddy......

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: Most Welcome..... Happy Coding.  :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98270/discussion-between-howliee-and-rk-rathod).

Answer (score 0):

The product options are saved as JSON.

With the MySQL version required by Magento 2, there seems to be no nice solution for this:

1. You can filter using LIKE "%2010%" or some [more sophisticated expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30411863/288568) to *emulate* JSON processing
2. As a second step you should `json_decode` the column within PHP to really check for the product_option in the JSON. That means 1. is just some kind of performance optimization - and not reliable.

Alternative:

If you MySQL version is a recent one, you can use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39163928/288568).